# Git response time of mounted folder is super slow over NFS or SSHFS

Tags: git, nfs, sshfs

I have a Git-enabled PHP project folder on a dev server and we run all our code on there (means we don't have to set up and host everything locally on our machines). I currently edit my code by mounting to a local folder.

I have done this via SSHFS and NFS, and both are suuuuuper slow when running tasks like **git status** (Weirdly enough, when I SSH to the server, **git status** returns immediately).

Ideally, I would like to be able to point git-cola at this folder and get it to respond in a reasonable time frame.

Can anyone advise on any methods of mounting a remote folder that will work in this situation?

Comment: I think you should use `git` as it supposed to work - work with local files on your local computer and push changes to your server instead of mapping repository over network

Comment: I agree, I would love to do that (and normally do), but in this situation there are a number of services also running on that server and it would be a pain in the arse for everyone to tinker with their local setups to get the whole environment working.